# How to redirect to a page after submitting form data?

Tags: redirect, forms, wpdb

I have a custom form which posts data to `wpdb`.

Currently, after form submit, my form keeps the user on the same page, but I'd like to redirect them to a thank you page.

Here is how the form is set up currently:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>?ref=<?php echo $reference; ?>" method="post">
// fields
</form>
```

**Note**: `$reference` is getting a query string from the URL.

I am then getting the data and posting it to `wpdb`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  insert_row();
}

function insert_row(){

  global $wpdb;

  $rsvp_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'rsvp';

  // get and sanitize fields
  $fullname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['full_name']);

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['rsvp_nonce'], 'rsvp_nonce' ) ) {
    return; // Nonce verification failed, do not insert data
  } else {
    $wpdb->insert($rsvp_table,
      array(
        'fullname' => $fullname,
      ),
      array(
        '%s', // fullname
      )
    );
  }

  if ( $wpdb->last_error !== '' ) {
    echo $wpdb->last_error;  // There was an error
  } else {
    echo 'Data was inserted successfully';  // Success
  }

}
```

Then, in `functions.php`, I have the following:

```
add_action('init', 'redirectAfterSubmit');

function redirectAfterSubmit() {
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    wp_redirect( "/thank-you", 301 );
    die();
    }
  }
}
```

Now, on form submit, this does redirect me to the thank you page, but it doesn't post the data to the database. The redirect is happening before posting the data it seems?

### Edit

My form markup and database insertion (inc form handling) is in a component called `rsvp.php` which is included on a custom template called `homepage`:

```
<?php

/* Template Name: Homepage */

get_header();
get_template_part('templates/components/rsvp');
get_footer();

?>
```

### Edit 2

Handle insertion of row before redirect in `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'redirectAfterSubmit');

function redirectAfterSubmit() {
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    insert_row();
    wp_redirect( "/thank-you", 301 );
    die();
  }
}

function insert_row(){
  // form handing here
}
```

Comment: where and when is your form handling code running? I notice that you didn't share where the form handling code was located or any information about when it runs. Can you edit your question to include this missing information? Is that code running in a page template? A shortcode? Hook?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell - Done. Have added the info the the question.

Comment: ah, you can't redirect after your form as long as the handling is inside a theme template. Redirects need to happen before any output occurs so that the right HTTP headers are sent, which also means your form handling needs to happen before then too

Comment: @TomJNowell - Ah, I see and makes sense. I've updated my question to showcase code snippet on what I think you're referring to (which looks to be working for me). May come in handy for others :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: can you post it as a solution/answer instead of a question edit? The site still thinks you haven't gotten an answer yet, and this isn't a forum/message board

Comment: @TomJNowell - Reason I've provided it as an edit is because I was asking you for confirmation on if it was what you were suggesting / best practise. Once I had that, I was planning to post it as the answer :)

Comment: if it works it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form handling needs to happen in `functions.php` (or equivalent) so that it triggers before headers are sent. Here is the how I achieved redirection after form submit:

```
add_action('init', 'redirectAfterSubmit');

function redirectAfterSubmit() {
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    insert_row();
    wp_redirect( "/thank-you", 301 );
    die();
  }
}

function insert_row(){
  // form handing here
}
```

Comment: Just note that `template_redirect` is the conventional hook to use when redirecting. What you have will probably work, so it's not wrong, but `template_redirect` is the convention.